# Substring word boundaries with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, cpu-word

I'm 99% of there with a regex to find words, but not any iterations of where that occurs as a substring.

ie Looking for **jam** or **JAM** but not Pa**jam**a or floro**jam**

This is what I have [so far](https://regex101.com/r/BPMg3W/1/):

```
\bjam\s?\d?\b
```

It works with all the combinations I'm likely to encounter except that I would like it to also pick up on multiple iterations of the same string with no spaces

```
jamjamjamjam
```

Is there away I can add that to the regex?

Comment: Try: `\b(?:jam\h*\d*)+\b`

Comment: @anubhava not working https://regex101.com/r/C05fsI/1

Comment: I am under impression that OP wants to match `jamjamjamjam`

Comment: @anubhava ah? I was almost sure he meant that he *didn't* want to match them. Maybe you're right.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy - Sorry that was my bad wording. I'm much better with pictures :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex with alternation:

```
~\b(?:(?:jam)+|jam\h*\d*)\b~i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BPMg3W/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?:(?:jam)+|jam\h*\d*)`: Match 1+ adjacent `jam` strings or `jam` followed by 0+ whitespaces and 0+ digits
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `i`: mode for ignore case

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this :

```
\b(?:jam|JAM)+\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/C05fsI/4